# Does the Streaming API required to be enabled for a Salesforce Organization before being subscribed to?

Tags: rest-api, streaming-api

If one would build a Salesforce integration with OAuth using the REST API and the Streaming API. Is there any special configuration do the users who would install this integration need to have in their Salesforce Organization?

For example, if perhaps is there a setting they need to enable before Streaming API can be used.

My goal is once the client authenticates the integration OAuth App via Salesforce OAuth, and I gain their access token, I would create a PushTopic and use a CometD client library to subscribe to that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/)

- The “API Enabled” permission must be enabled for your Developer
  Edition organization. This permission is enabled by default, but may
  have been changed by an administrator.
- The “Streaming API” permission must be enabled.

> To verify that the “API Enabled” and “Streaming API” permissions are
>   enabled in your organization, from Setup, enter User Interface in the
>   Quick Find box, then select User Interface.

- The logged-in user must have “Read” permission on the PushTopic
  standard object to receive notifications.
- The logged-in user must have “Create” permission on the PushTopic
  standard object to create and manage PushTopic records.
- The logged-in user must have “Author Apex” permissions to create a
  PushTopic by using the Developer Console.